# My Discord Bot is online. My Prefix is "-". My -Ping Command is working but my -Discord command is not working. My Code is below. (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

**This is my Code ⬇️. My -Ping Command is working but my -Discord Command is not. My Bot is also online, Is there a problem?**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const prefix = '-'

client.once('ready', () => {
     console.log('Super-Lame is Online!')
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    } else if (command === 'Discord'){
        message.channel.send('LecTroLight#9823');
    }
});

client.login('My Token Here')
```

Answer (score 0):

With `toLowerCase()`, you converted `command` to lowercase, so it will never equal `"Discord"`. You should match against `"discord"`.

Comment: OMG! I'm really dumb. I didn't even saw that.. Thanks You SOOO Much Dude. You're my savior.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed you are using
**.toLowerCase()** and then you are checking the conditions for ***Discord***. That wont work unless you check for ***discord***.